# how to show f is bijective?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, several-complex-variables

Suppose that the set-mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of one-dimensional domains of $\mathbb{C}$ induces an isomorphism $f^0:\mathcal{O}(Y)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(X)$ defined by $g\mapsto g\circ f$ of topological algebras.Show that $f$ is bijective.\
My idea is to suppose $f$ is not bijective,dividing this problem into two cases,i.e. $f$ is not injective or $f$ is not surjective,then I want to conduct a contradiction that $f^0$ cannot be an isomorphism in any two cases.But I can't find where the contradiction lies.Can you help me?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not injective, say $f(z_1) = f(z_2) = w_0 \in Y$, let $h(w) = w-w_0$. Then $h$ is prime in $\mathcal{O}(Y)$. What about $f^0(h)$?

If $f$ is not surjective, let $w_0 \in Y \setminus f(X)$, and $h(w) = w-w_0$. What can you say about $f^0(h)$ that distinguishes it from $h$ algebraically?

Comment: Essentially I just need to use the fact that the algebra-isomorphism preserves units,nonunits and prime elements. Moveover I can conclude that $f$ is actually biholomorphic. Thank you!You are great!

Comment: Right. You don't need to consider the topological structure of $\mathcal{O}(X)$ at all.